# textboxes reads empty string ("") when i press submit button!

Tags: asp.net, form-submit

I have a form , with 5 textboxes, 1 radiobutton group (4 radiobuttons) , and a submit button, 
i added some "code behind" to handle cases where a user doesnt fill in all the fields,

something like

```
 if (question.Value == "") // question = a textbox with runat=server property
{
  // handle error
}
```

the problem is that, the 1st time i fill the form,and click submit, it always sends empty values :S
in other words. the above snippet of code will always be true :S
can some1 explain to me where did i go wrong ?

note: if the same question been asked before.. please link me..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to check and see if you databinding on your button post back is not blanking out your textboxes. You can use;

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    // more code here
}
```

to make sure that your input items keep their values when you click your button.

Comment: @chris: hmm, somehow u helped me figure out the issue, the problem was that i had a a piece of code that clears the data on pageload() :D
seems like it was causing the uproar... i just added a clear form button instead :D

Answer (score 2):

Assuming question is a textbox, you want question.Text

Comment: @ chris : .. it works after the 1st postback.. so i assume i am using the right properties :)..